# Failed to install PyOpenCL on ubuntu 18.04 and AMD R9 Fury

Tags: pyopencl

First off, I was able to install everything just fine with ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

With a new SSD drive, I did a clean install with ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After 3 clean installs I finally got the AMD GPU Pro driver installed with openCL legacy option. (FYI, it was because of a silly reason: with Secure boot turned ON, the installation will prompt you for generating a private key, but it never appears.)
Also, I wrongly also installed the AMD APP SDK 3 (as somewhere said I don't need it anymore?)

Checking clinfo, it shows my devices as expected.
I also got the opencl-headers installed.

Then I moved on to install pip3, jupyter and then PyOpenCL.
Upon trying to install PyOpenCL using pip3, it shows this error:

```
    /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Would you have any idea?

PS: Somehow I can install PyOpenCL using apt-get, however. Not sure if this is a good way though.